# Signing data with .NET Core 5, I get the error "Error occurred during a cryptographic operation."

Tags: .net-core, cryptography, rsa, x509, pkcs#7

I get an error when trying to sign data with .NET Core using CMS with certificate

```csharp
X509Store st = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
st.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certSelected = st.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
st.Close();

var signerCert = certSelected[0];

ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(msg);
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(signerCert);
cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);
```

I get the error below when computing the signature

```log4j
Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.Windows.HelpersWindows.GetProvParameters(SafeProvOrNCryptKeyHandle handle)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.Windows.PkcsPalWindows.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean silent, Boolean preferNCrypt)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.Windows.PkcsPalWindows.GetPrivateKeyForSigning[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean silent)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSignature.RSAPkcs1CmsSignature.Sign(ReadOnlySpan`1 dataHash, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithmName, X509Certificate2 certificate, AsymmetricAlgorithm key, Boolean silent, String& signatureAlgorithm, Byte[]& signatureValue)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSignature.Sign(ReadOnlySpan`1 dataHash, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithmName, X509Certificate2 certificate, AsymmetricAlgorithm key, Boolean silent, String& oid, ReadOnlyMemory`1& signatureValue)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner.Sign(ReadOnlyMemory`1 data, String contentTypeOid, Boolean silent, X509Certificate2Collection& chainCerts)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.ComputeSignature(CmsSigner signer, Boolean silent)
```

The same code works in .NET Framework 4.5.2

Any idea what could be wrong here and how to fix it in .NET Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working by:

- defining the Oid in ContentInfo
- defining the Oid in CmsSigner
- using a different constructor for CmsSigner

New code below with the changes

```csharp
X509Store st = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
st.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certSelected = st.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
st.Close();

var signerCert = certSelected[0];

Oid dstOid = new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.2"); // PKCS#7
ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(dstOid, msg);
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);

CmsSigner signerWindowStore = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, signerCert, signerCert.GetRSAPrivateKey());
signerWindowStore.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26"); // SHA1
signerWindowStore.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signerWindowStore, false);
```